# angular ng-options select wont select the current value as the select value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-options

i have a select where I am setting an ng-model and a list of options. When I update the value it updates fine in the scope, however when I try to reload the page it wont start with the correct value selected.

```
<select ng-change="updateSelectedNotification()"
ng-model="selectedNotification.notification_type"
ng-options="type.name for type in notificationTypes"
class="chosen-select"></select>
```

Comment: why would you expect the value will be saved on page refresh (unless you persisted it in the backend)? do you know any select-box that behaves that way?

Comment: Where you store selected value – from where AngularJS should to know what is the selected option?

Comment: I save the value to the DB through ng-change. It is persisted and in the notification object after refresh.

Comment: In that case, if the value is being persisted, the problem may be in the controller initalization, after you grab the previously persisted data from the server. Could you show that code?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are not initializing the select to be what you set it as.  Luckily angular provides a way for you to do this with the [ng-init](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit) directive.

```
<select
    ng-change="updateSelectedNotification()"
    ng-model="selectedNotification.notification_type"
    ng-options="type.value as type.name for type in notificationTypes track by $index"
    ng-init="selectedNotification.notification_type = selected"
    class="chosen-select">
</select>

$scope.selected = (your persisted value of type.value);
```

Notice the track by in the ng-options.  The basic idea is to use ng-init to set your model to one of the values from ng-options.  You can also always set the value to the first item in your array instead of having a blank first option like so.

```
ng-init="selectedNotification.notification_type = notificationTypes[0]"
```

Just be sure to match the value that is assigned each option tag when the markup is generated. You can use ng-options to do this for you with type.value as type.name.  This will set the value properties to type.value, and the text as type.name. So if you have the persisted value you can just assign it in your viewmodel like shown above.